# Similarity score between two sets of tokens

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a set of urls retrieved for a person. I want to try and classify each url as being about that person (his/her linkedin profile or blog or news article mentioning the person) or not about that person.

I am trying to apply a rudimentary approach where I tokenize each webpage and compare to all others to see how many similar words (excluding stop words) there are between each document and then take the most similar webpages to be positive matches.

I am wondering if there is a machine learning approach I can take to this which will make my task easier and more accurate. Essentially I want to compare webpage content (tokenized into words) between two webpages and determine a score for how similar they are based on their content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with python this NLP classifier should help you greatly:
http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#module-nltk.classify

For unsupervised clustering you can use this:
http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.cluster.html#module-nltk.cluster

If you are simply looking for similarity scores then the metrics module should be useful:
http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics

NLP-toolkit has the answer, just browse through the modules to find what you want, and don't implement it by hand.

Comment: classifiers would require me to select features first. In this case, i do not have any previous info about what is (or could be) on the web pages i wish to run similarity analysis on.